# Javascript array join does not work correctly

Tags: javascript

I have the following array and I want to join it into a number

```js
    const arr = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]
    const digits = arr.join("") //6145390195186705543
    const digitsToNumber = +arr.join("") //6145390195186705000
    console.log(digits);
    console.log(digitsToNumber);
```

You can see that the join function works. However, when I try to convert it into a number, it shows a weird value. Do you guys know why it happened that way?

Comment: *when I try to convert it into a number, it shows a weird value* what weird value? You title and the actual question also appear to have very little in common

Comment: I assume you mean `arr.join`, but check out `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: Right, `digits.join("")` should be `arr.join(...)`

Comment: It's weird, that the number to convert is exactly the same as in the question 0stone0 has linked ..?

Comment: @Teemu https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/javascript-coding-exercise/214499 via leetcode.

Comment: @Dave Nice catch, that makes the questions real duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will log different results because you are exceeding Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - the highest value JS can safely compare and represent numbers.

One method to check if you are ever exceeding the limit (besides remembering the value) is [Number.isSafeInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger)

```
Number.isSafeInteger(digitsToNumber); //false
```

From the docs: For larger integers, consider using the BigInt type.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285586/javascript-array-join-does-not-work-correctly#comment120684720_68285586), the value is too large for JavaScript and is truncated.

We can use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to prevent this. Use with caution!

```js
const arr = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]

const digits = arr.join(''); 
const digitsToNumber = +arr.join(""); 
const bigDigitsToNumber = BigInt(arr.join(''));


console.log(digits);                          // 6145390195186705543
console.log(digitsToNumber);                  // 6145390195186705000
console.log(bigDigitsToNumber.toString());    // 6145390195186705543
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert your concatenated string into a number you could use parseInt("123") method.

```
const number= parseInt(digitsToNumber)
```

However because of your number is too big or could be bigger, Javascript can not handle that numbers which contains more than 16 digit. If you also have a problem like that you can use some external big number libraries like [BigNumber.Js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/).

Edit: According to Teemu's comment, you could also use [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) native big integer handling library.

Comment: The `+` is not a typo, it is one way to convert a string into a number. It's not the number of digits but the value of those digits.

Comment: Oh sorry, i edited it

Comment: The numbers still differ